# make a friendly multi-language website

Tags: php, web-crawler, multilingual

Just to make things clear.

I'm trying to figure out how to build a website with a language chooser.

The language chooser is just refreshing the current page but altering the session variable "language" (if the user comes in for the first time I set it up to 'eng').

Now let's figure out the way the crawler is doing, it visits the site and the language is automatically chosen for it, so basically it recognizes the website language and classified it as 'eng'.

I'm just not sure this is the right way to go building a multi-language website since the crawler won't be scanning the pages in a different set of language again, am I right ? (or maybe it can detect that the language has been modified and rescan all the pages...which sounds a bit fancy). So the pages won't be referencing in the search engines database. So what is the right way to build those kind of websites ?

**EDIT :** I'm thinking about the mod_rewrite, do you think it's a great solution ?

Comment: Have the language show up somewhere in URL. Like `site.com/en/`, `en.site.com`, or `site.com/?lang=en`. This way the crawlers will eventually reach the URLs for different languages.

Comment: Don' care about Searchengines. Care about your users and your content… BTW. http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200901/specify_each_html_documents_main_natural_language/

Comment: As a note... you can set the document language per page... So you define something like <html lang="de"> or <html lang="en"> in your head. Searchengines take care about this...

Comment: @gearsdigital for sure I care about the users, that's why I try to figure out how to reference the same content in a different language so that a set of foreigner can reach my website.

Comment: Best way is to use a wordpress approach and using e_()

Comment: @Shef google cares about options ? I mean I don't see any page with options referenced in the search engine.

Comment: @Tom can you post this as an answer ? I get interested in. thanks

Comment: @Oddantfr Yes, it does care about them. It will try to reduce them to a minimum by taking them away, but if the content differs it will use them. Run this `inurl:?lang=en` in Google to see the number of indexed pages with the language variable in the URL.

Comment: Have a look at [this comment I made](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20143/what-are-pitfalls-in-seo-when-internationalizing-a-website#comment-18907) as well on [this question on webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20143/what-are-pitfalls-in-seo-when-internationalizing-a-website)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve this by making the language as a url attribute for instance:

> www.example.com/en/
>
> www.example.com/fr/

Those will be able to crawl and handle content with different languages.

more explained [here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=182192#1)

Comment: and what about the path format ?
www.example.com/fr/home (home is not really French, could it constraint the way my website is referenced ?)

Comment: you can fix that through your mod_rewrite, as making the url as clean as you want to show it, some ppl do leave it as it is ( i.e http://www.google.com/support/accounts/?hl=fr )

Answer (score 1):

> I'm thinking about the mod_rewrite, do you think it's a great solution ?

Yes.